# Solving improper integral involving product logarithm and exponentials

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, lambert-w

It is possible to verify or show numerically that

$\displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}W(e^{x-e^{x}})dx=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$

$W(x)$ is the Lambert W function.

This integral does not seem to have a solution in terms of elementary or standard functions.

Is it possible to prove or solve it analytically, or to find a symbolic solution?

Comment: How did arrive at this integral ?

Comment: I found the exact same question here: https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-this-equation-int-infty-infty-W-e-x-e-x-dx-frac-pi-2-12

Answer (score 6):

The substitution $y=e^x$ obtains your integral as $\int_0^\infty y^{-1}W(ye^{-y})dy$. Writing$$W(z)=\sum_{n\ge 1} w_n z^n$ with $w_n:=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!},$$we can rewrite this integral as$$\sum_n\dfrac{w_n\Gamma(n)}{n^n}=\sum_n (-1)^{n-1} n^{-2}=\dfrac{1}{2}\zeta(2).$$

Comment: Caution should be applied to this method due to the radius of convergence for this series, ie $z< 1/|e|$.

Comment: @Leucippus But $y\in\mathbb{R}^+\implies z:=ye^{-y}\in (0,\,1/e]$.

Comment: @ J.G. $y=e^{-x}$ or more likely $y=e^{x}$ ?

Comment: @fsrong70 Thanks; fixed.